# WPF MVVM updated element not updating GUI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a class like this:

```
public class ResourceList : ObservableCollection<Resource>
{
    public ResourceList() : base()
    {
    }
}

public class Resource
{
    public Resource()
    {
        Name = "";
        EMail = "";
        Date = "";
        Time = "";
        SWList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EMail { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<string> SWList { get; set; }
}

public class Licenses : ObservableCollection<Licenses>
{
    public Licenses()
    {
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string License { get; set; }
}
```

and the following two Commands, which pretty much looks the same:

```
internal class ReadResourceFilesCommand : ICommand
{
    public ReadResourceFilesCommand(ResourceViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private ResourceViewModel _viewModel;

    #region ICommand Members

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _viewModel.CanUpdate;
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.ReadResourceFile(parameter.ToString());
    }
    #endregion
}



internal class ReadInventoryFilesCommand : ICommand
{
    public ReadInventoryFilesCommand(ResourceViewModel viewModel)
    {
        _viewModel = viewModel;
    }

    private ResourceViewModel _viewModel;

    #region ICommand Members

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _viewModel.CanUpdate;
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _viewModel.ReadInventroyFiles(parameter.ToString());
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and my viewModel `CanUpdate` and `ResourceList` looks like this:

```
public bool CanUpdate
{
    get
    {
        if (ResourceList == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public ResourceList ResourceList
{
    get
    {
        return _ResourceList;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == _ResourceList)
            return;

        _ResourceList = value;

        // INotifyPropertyChanged Method for updating the binding
        onPropertyChanged("ResourceList");
    }
}
```

Now the actual problem:
When the first command is executed, does not matter which one, the **listView** in the **GUI** is being populated and everything looks fine. But when the other command is executed (which actually updated the elements in the same list, the *Time* and *Date* attributes of all elements will be updated) the **listView** will not update its elements.

*I am aware that I am not changing the whole list, I am updating some of the elements inside it* and that might be why it is not being updated. But I really don't know how to proceed?
Please explain how I should modify the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Resource class does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

This interface causes the View to be notified of changes to the instances of Resource. Just like ObservableCollection notifies the View of changes to the collection (add, delete, move items)

```
public class Resource : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Resource()
    {
        Name = "";
        EMail = "";
        Date = "";
        Time = "";
        SWList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    // TODO: do this for all properties:

    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name;}
        set 
        {
            if(name != value) 
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }



    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I pointed out I am new to all of this. Could you please elaborate with code?

Comment: @theAlse - I Just added an example.

Comment: Note that there are a couple of way to implement INottifyPropertyChanged, this is just one of them and the most straight forward. Search for more implementations (and discussions) on this site.

Comment: BTW: you might also need to change the License class.

Comment: Just to clarify: the first update is successful due to the fact that the PropertyChanged event is being raised on list initialization.